# How to navigate from popover view controller in swift?

Tags: swift, view

I have a button on a view controller and by clicking that button a view controller appears as a popup. That popup has a tableview and whenever I click on the tableview row I want it to navigate to different view controller. But I think it is not as simple as using this code.

```
let vc = storyboard?instantiateViewController(identifier: "controller") as! Controller
           
            self.navigationController.pushViewController(popupView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is there a way to open a view controller from popup view?

Comment: Your code would work if the popup VC is in a navigation controller.

Comment: Popup is in a navigation controller but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What's the error message? What actually happened?

Comment: There is no error message. Whenever I click on the row it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please, post a [mcve].